# SQL Server - Find all tables/columns used by a query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to analyse a list of queries to find out dependencies of reports to certain tables/fields to attempt to document the impact of the refactoring of a data structure.

Is there any way to (maybe utilize the SQL Server query parser to) find out which tables/fields are being used based on a query string input?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` and run the query (in another batch).

This will return you an `XML` with the expected execution plan.

You can search it for `//ColumnReference` which would contain `@Database`, `@Schema`, `@Table` and `@Column`.

Note however that the optimizer may decide to expand views (if you are using them), optimize out some tables (if it decides they are not needed) etc. This may also help in refactoring though.

Also you can run `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and read the output. It will show you actual I/O on the tables used by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the execution plan of the queries and then post-process that output to get close to what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735(v=sql.105).aspx

is a starting point for the SHOWPLAN_ALL T-SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

If you create views or stored procedures for the queries, then [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) wil list the dependencies on other database objects.